# Updating an input whose value attribute is bound to an observable, after editing the input

Tags: knockout.js

[Here is an example on jsFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/n6sHt/)

I have some HTML with Knockout bindings to display a value `x` both as the value of an `input` and as text in a `p` tag.

```
<p data-bind="text: x"></p>
<p><input id="x" data-bind="attr: {value: x}"></p>
<button id="update">Update</button>
```

What I want this to do is take the value in the `input` when the Update button is pressed, round it to the nearest integer, and have it display this rounded value in both places. I tried this:

```
var vm = {
    x: ko.observable(1)
};

ko.applyBindings(vm);

$('#update').click(function () {
    vm.x(Math.round($('#x').val()));
});
```

[Here's the jsFiddle link again.](http://jsfiddle.net/n6sHt/)

When you load it, the initial value of `1` is displayed in both places. If you change the value in the `input` to `2` and click the "Update" button, then both places will display `2`. Wonderful. This works for any integer.

Now try something that's not an integer. Enter `5.3` and press "Update". The `p` correctly updates to display `5`, but the `input` still shows `5.3`.

[Some further investigation](http://jsfiddle.net/n6sHt/2/) seems to indicate that Knockout is happy to update the `input` until I manually edit the value in the `input`, at which point it stops doing anything to the `input`. I can understand why this might be desirable in some cases to prevent user input from being overwritten... but it's not the behavior I want. How can I get it to update both displayed values when the view model is updated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you change your fiddle to use `data-bind="value: x"` intead of `data-bind="attr: {value: x}"` it will work perfectly.

Comment: Yep, just read the documentation. The `value` binding is bidirectional, whereas `attr` bindings are unidirectional. In other words, `value` will both update the attached observable and read the value from the attached observable, whereas `attr` binding just reads from the observable.

Comment: This isn't exactly what I wanted because it updates the underlying view model with whatever is in the form field until the Submit button is pressed, but it's close enough. It seems that a workaround to this could be done kind of like [this](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/extenders.html) but it would probably be really messy.